# When should prefetch be used on modern machines?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, x86, avx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prefetching Examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327994/prefetching-examples)

In many cases prefetch instructions seem to slow performance on modern machines, because there are typically a few different hardware prefetch units.

Are there any particular cases where it always helps to use prefetch instructions?

Comment: Pretty much whenever the access pattern is non-trivial, but known to the programmer. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327994/prefetching-examples That said, the speedups tend to be marginal at best.

Comment: Ahh right, sorry I misread that question.