# why is there a need to stop prefetching to pages when a write happens to it?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, intel, cpu-cache, prefetch

I read in this StackOverflow answer that prefetching does not happen for dirty pages.

[In which condition DCU prefetcher start prefetching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517653/in-which-condition-dcu-prefetcher-start-prefetching/53553395#53553395)

> It seems to me that the prefetcher is receiving the dirty flag from the page table entry of the page being accessed (from the TLB). The flag indicates whether page is dirty or not. If it's dirty, the prefetcher will not track the page and accesses to the page will not be counted towards the three accesses for the triggering condition to be satisfied. So it seems that the DCU prefetcher simply ignores dirty pages. That said, the page doesn't have to be read-only though to be supported by the prefetcher. However, more thorough investigation is required to understand more accurately how stores may interact with the DCU prefetcher.

> This suggests that if there is a stream of a large number of stores intertwined with few loads, the L1 prefetcher will ignore the loads and basically temporarily switch off until the stores become a minority. However, my experimental results show that even a single store to a page will turn the prefetcher off for that page.

Why is there a need to stop prefetching from pages to which store happens?

Is it beacuse there is a write buffer in the middle and the prefetcher will have to check the write buffer too if there is a store?

Comment: If that's how it actually works, perhaps the idea is that L2 hits (since the L2 prefetcher will keep working) are "good enough" for stores.  Or perhaps they're avoiding some bad corner case where read prefetches made NT stores much worse?  Or maybe DCU prefetch only requests Shared state, and if this is a load / modify / store in-place modification of some data, then an RFO would still be required to get Exclusive/Modified state?  *Those are total guesses assuming these facts are all true: I haven't looked into this detail of the prefetcher.*

Comment: It seems really unlikely to me that the page-table / TLB dirty flag would stop some prefetching from working.  Most stack, dynamically-allocated, BSS, and `.data` memory will have that flag set, since the OS won't normally sync it such pages to the pagefile.  *Only* never-modified pages, or ones that haven't been modified after being swapped back in, would not have the Dirty flag set, and it doesn't make sense to me that it would be worth having any significant prefetch hardware just for that special case.  Except maybe for code-prefetch, although JIT is an important use-case.