# Minimizing page faults (and TLB faults) while "walking" a large graph

Tags: performance, graph, x86, garbage-collection, page-fault

Problem (think of the mark phase of a GC)

- I have a graph of “objects” that I need to walk, visiting all objects.
- I can store in each object if it has been visited.
- All the objects are stored in memory and linked together using normal pointers.
- The objects are not all the same size.
- Sometimes there is not enough ram in the system to hold all the objects in memory at the same time, and I wish to avoid “page thrashing”.
- I also wish to avoid TLB faults
- Other times, there is more than enough ram.
- I do not mind writing low-level code.
- I do not mind different code for windows and linux.
- The code must run in “user space” without needing none standard permissions.
- I don't care the order I visit the nodes in.

I am going to ask more detail questions about possible solutions, linking back to this questions.

Comment: For TLB thrashing you could ask for large pages but this ofc works *against* the fact that you might not have enough RAM.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you wish to implement your own page replacement algorithm? [Hash Don't Cache (The Page Tables)](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~dan/papers/hvsr-sigmetrics-2016.pdf) paper might be useful.

Comment: @Tony, no I wish to implement my own garbage collector that works well when memory is short.

Comment: In general - do you visit a tree in in well-defined order? If so, you can flatten such tree into linear array - for example in case of pre-order depth-first, each element being a node, storing a pointer to its parent. After such flattening elements in nodes array are always located after already processed parent and sequential access is all good from the memory access perspective.
But in GC context - it unlikely you will pre-process objects graph to flatten it before traversal. In such case partitioning/generations and compacting (locality) are your friends.

Comment: Sorry - I understand the optimization goal (minimizing paging), I just don't see what you are trying to optimize. Are you dealing with a pre-existing graph  in memory, and is your only choice which node to visit next? (Which for a single-linked list is no choice at all.) Or do you actually control the location in memory of all these objects? Because in the latter case, you can choose to place close nodes together in memory.

Comment: @MSalters, I am dealing with a pre-existing graph in memory that is highly interconnected.

Comment: Are you restricted to one thread? Because with multipel CPU cores, you also get multiple TLB's. And it's no big deal if a thread stalls waiting for a page-in. But multi-threaded graph walks are far more complex even if they don't alter the graph.

Comment: @MSalters, but a page-in will result in a page-out, hence I wish to delay page-ins until I have visited as many nodes memory resident nodes as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Page faults aren't necessarily bad, as long as they're not stalling your progress.

This means that if you have a node `Node* p` with two candidate successors `p->left` and `p->right`, it can be useful to pick the nearest (in terms of `(char*)p - (char*)p->next`) and pre-fetch the other (e.g. with [PrefetchVirtualMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh780543(v=VS.85).aspx)).

How efficient this will be cannot be predicted; it greatly depends on your graph topology. But the prefetch is virtually free when you have enough RAM.

Closer to the CPU, there's [cache prefetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327994/prefetching-examples). Same idea, different storage

Comment: page faults (unlike TLB misses) do stall your progress.  A PF exception is handled by the kernel, so out-of-order execution of the rest of your code isn't happening.  Meltdown + Spectre mitigation makes user->kernel->user round-trips extra expensive.  (But still cheap compared to waiting for I/O to the swap file, which is the kind of page thrashing the OP is talking about.)  If another another task can run while waiting for that I/O, then great, but in a thrashing situation its working set is probably partly swapped out, too.  (upvoted for the rest of the answer, though.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I got the impression that `PrefetchVirtualMemory` would page in the requested address from within the kernel, but return immediately before the page was brought in. That's why you can process another node in parallel.

Comment: Right, you can start the I/O ahead of time, and that's excellent.  I'm not sure you can avoid the soft page fault to wire the page into the HW page table, unless the kernel modifies the page table of a process that's running on another CPU core.  (On x86 it's safe to change a PTE from invalid to valid; the ISA guarantees no software-visible negative-caching in the TLB).  Cheapening a hard page fault (wait for disk) to a soft page fault (just CPU activity) is very worth it if you know when it's actually needed, but a soft PF is still a user->kernel->user that Spectre mitigation makes expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Use 2M hugepages for address ranges that are full of "hot" data that the kernel can't usefully swap out any / many 4k chunks of.  This will reduce TLB misses, but costs extra physical memory if there are any 4k chunks of a hugepage that aren't hot.

Linux does this transparently for anonymous pages (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/transhuge.txt), but you can use [`madvise(MADV_HUGEPAGE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) on pages you know are worth it, to encourage the kernel to defrag physical memory even if that's not the default in `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag`.  (You can look at `/proc/PID/smaps` to see how many transparent hugepages are in use for any given mapping.)

---

Based on what you posted in your answer: **An *ordered* set of `nodesToVisit` would give you the most locality, but might be too expensive to maintain**.  Multiple accesses within the same 64-byte cache line are *much* cheaper than coming back to it later after it's been evicted from L3 cache and has to come from DRAM again.

If you have lots of addresses to visit in your Set, doing one pass of a radix-sort into 2M buckets would give you locality within one hugepage.  2M is also smaller than L3 cache size, so you'll probably get some cache hits when visiting multiple objects in the same cache line, even if you don't hit them back to back.

Depending on how big your Set is, throwing around that many pointers even to partial-sort them might not be worth the memory traffic that takes.  But there's probably some sweet spot of taking a window of data and at least partially sorting it.  Using the pointers before *they* are evicted from cache is nice.

**SW prefetch can trigger a page-walk to avoid a TLB miss, so you could [`_mm_prefetch(_MM_HINT_T2)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,SVML,Other&expand=1276,4104&text=_mm_pr) one address from the next 2M bucket before starting on the current bucket.**  See also [Prefetching Examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327994/prefetching-examples).  I haven't tested this, but it might work well.  It won't help with page faults: prefetch from an unmapped page won't cause a page fault, and you don't want to trigger an actual PF until you're ready to touch the page.

MSalter's suggestion to ask the OS to prefetch and wire the next page is interesting (I think `madvise(MADV_WILLNEED)` is the Linux equivalent), but a system call will be slow for no benefit if the page was already mapped+wired into the HW page table.  There's no x86 asm instruction that just asks if a page is mapped without faulting if it isn't, so I can't think of a way to efficiently choose not to call it.  And BTW, I think Linux breaks up transparent hugepages into 4k regular pages for paging in/out.  But don't write a big loop that just does `_mm_prefetch()` or `madvise` on all the 4k pages in a 2M block; that probably sucks.  The `prefetcht2` part would probably just result in excess prefetch requests being dropped.

Use perf counters to look at cache hit/miss rates.  On Intel CPUs, the `mem_load_retired.l1_miss` and/or `.l2_miss` event should show you whether you're getting cache hits on accessing the Set itself, as well as on accessing dereferencing those pointers.  Those counters are precise events, so they should map accurately to asm load instructions.  (e.g. `perf record -e mem_load_retired.l2_miss ./my_program` / `perf report` on Linux).

> We remove one item at a time from `nodesToVisit`

I don't know much about GC design, but can't you use a sequence number or tagged-pointer or something to avoid modifying the Set data structure itself every GC pass?  If your minimum object alignment is 4 bytes, you have 2 bits to play with at the bottom of every pointer.  ANDing them off before dereferencing is very cheap.

x86-64 with full 64-bit pointers currently requires the top 16 to be the sign-extension of the low 48.  So you could use bits there (16 bits, or maybe just the top byte) if you re-canonicalize pointers.  (redo sign extension, or just zero the high 16 bits if you want to assume user-space pointers; Linux uses a high-half kernel VM layout so user-space addresses are always in the low half of virtual address space.  IDK what Windows does.)

**On x86-64, you might consider using the [x32 ABI (32-bit pointers in long mode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) if 4GiB of address space is enough**, especially if you're hitting physical memory limits and swapping.  Smaller pointers mean smaller data structures, thus half the cache footprint.

Some Linux systems are built without kernel support for x32, though, only classic x86-64 and usually 32-bit mode.  But if it works on your systems, consider `gcc -mx32`.

Comment: forget about the "set" because a stack will work just as well, as visiting a node more than once is a "no-opp".

Comment: @IanRingrose: do you grow this set/stack as you visit nodes and discover more pointers?  So you have to build it from scratch every sweep?  I was hoping you could keep it around between sweeps so sorting it once could pay off for multiple reuses.

Comment: The graph is mutated, including nodes being removed between passes.   And there is no way to know about all "Live" nodes until after the walking of the graph has completed.   Think of the graph as being ALL live java objects in a process.

Answer (score 0):

These are my first thoughts about a possible solution, they are clearly not optimal.   I will delete this answer if someone posts a better answer.

**The basic method:**

- Assume we have a `Set<NodePointer> nodesToVisit` that contains all nodes we have not yet visited.
- We remove one item at a time from `nodesToVisit`,

  - and if it has not been visited before we add all “pointers to other nodes” to nodesToVisit.

**Improvements**:

But we can clearly do better, by ordering nodesToVisit  based on address, so that we are more likely to visit nodes that are contained in pages we have recently accessed.    This could be as simple as having a second `Set<NodePointer> nodesToVisitLater`, and putting any node that has an address a long way from the current node into it.

Or we could skip over any node that are contained in pages that are not resident in memory, visiting these nodes after we have visited all nodes that are currently in memory.

(The"set" could just be a stack, as visiting a node more than once is a "no-opp")

---

https://patents.google.com/patent/US7653797B1/en seems to be related, but I have not read it yet.
https://hosking.github.io/links/Cher+2004ASPLOS.pdf
https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/cramm.pdf
https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/f034-hertz.pdf
https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/04-16.pdf