# It is possible to load data from a page without updating the “most recent accessed” flag?

Tags: performance, x86, page-fault

I am thinking about [Minimizing page faults (and TLB faults) while “walking” a large graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221391/minimizing-page-faults-and-tlb-faults-while-walking-a-large-graph)

This is a long shot, but I wish to be able to load data from a page into a register, without updating the “most recent access flag”, as I know that data being loaded from my thread will no be touched again for a long time.   Therefore I do not wish to delay the eviction of the page from memory if the OS is getting short of ram.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, No.

This is not a thing controlled by the software, the CPU will set the *A* bit of page structure when it uses it.
To this point, the *A* bit may even leaks when in a transaction or make a transaction abort (if the CPU need to flip the *A* bit from 0 to 1).

I believe you are overthinking it, the OS will not rely only on the *A* bit to implement a LRU policy for the pages.
You can also manually allocate the pages before your critical code starts and deallocate them after it finishes.

If I were you I would focus on *considering* using `prefetchnta + load` to avoid polluting the cache too much since it is much smaller than the system memory.
See this [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844984/5801661) on how to use it and know its pitfalls (it's a brittle pattern).